# How to retrieve images from database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model with a `nvarchar` image file that I want to show on the page. How can I do that without going back to the database?

How can it display images?

Although I was trying to do it, but I get an error:

> Cannot convert string to byte'

Comment: **SHOW US** your code!! And preferably also your table structures involved in this.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my reputation I can't post a comment but your question is too vague to properly answer. Handling images can be done in multiple ways so you'll have to clarify how you're handling them right now. Also add the related code and possibly the database structure to your question.

In the current state of your question it is impossible to tell what is going wrong because you are giving little to no factors to work with. Post some of the source code!

Comment: <!-- here is code -->                                                                                                   
 <td rowspan="3">
 @{
var imgsrc = "url_to_your_default_image"; // useful when image is not available
  if (item.img != null) {
      var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.img);
       imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                                                    }
           <img src='@imgsrc' style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
                                                }
 </td>

Comment: I still can't fully make up the full context, but your use of string.Format seems a bit strange. Your code will result in `"data:/image/jpg;base64,url_that_was_in_item"`  as the final string. Maybe try doing something like this `imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg/{0}", base64);` which will return `"data:image/jpg/url_that_was_in_item"` as a resulting string. I think the error is caused due to your use of string.Format. An alternative could be using `$'data:image/jpg/{base64}'` which will do the same as the above string.Format.